# How do I add something to Django's response context after a successful login?

Tags: django, authentication

I have a Django project in which I currently have a wrapper around the standard login view:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from myapp.forms import LoginForm

def login(request, *args, **kwargs):
    """Wrapper for auth.login."""
    kwargs['template_name'] = 'login.html'
    kwargs['authentication_form'] = LoginForm
    auth_view_response = auth_views.login(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return auth_view_response
```

This all works fine, but I want to add something to the response context on the next page, only if the login has been successful. I'm not sure how to:

1. Check that the user has successfully logged in after `auth_views.login()` was called, or
2. Add a variable that will show up in the context of the next page.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking about the first question:

> Check that the user has successfully logged in after auth_views.login() was called, or

Inside the view function check the `request.user.is_authenticated()`

Speaking of the second question, you can just add the variable in user session and then check it on that next page:

```
#in the view mentioned above    
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    request.session['some_key'] = "some_var"

#in the view, that represents the next page
foo = request.session.get('some_key',None)
#now you can add foo to template context
```

Comment: Thanks DataGreed. But where in the above view can I do `request.user.is_authenticated()`?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, I came up with an answer not long after posting my SO question.

I didn't need to do anything with the login view. Instead, I use the `user_logged_in` signal:

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in

def post_login_actions(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
        request.session['just_logged_in'] = True

user_logged_in.connect(post_login_actions, dispatch_uid="user_logged_in")
```

(I put that at the end of my `myapp/models/userprofile.py`.)

And then I have a `myapp/context_processors.py` like this:

```
from django.conf import settings

def membership_context(request):
    context = {
        'just_logged_in': request.session.get('just_logged_in', False),
    }
    # Now we've used any True setting for this, set it to False subsequent requests:
    request.session['just_logged_in'] = False
    return context
```

And, of course, include that in my settings' `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`:

```
from django.conf.global_settings import TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS += (
    'myapp.context_processors.membership_context',
)
```

Now, every template has a `just_logged_in` value in its context, that's usually False, but will be True on the first page view after the user has logged in.